# ¿Cómo paso mi app web de OpenVidu a producción con un frontend en Angular?

Tags: ubuntu

Estoy creando un app web basado en **OpenVidu**, Lo he instalado en un servidor de Ubuntu, y ya esta configurado, este es mi **.env**:

```
CERTIFICATE_TYPE=letsencrypt
DOMAIN_OR_PUBLIC_IP=servidorubuntu.com.co
HTTPS_PORT=443
KMS_URIS=["ws://localhost:8888/kurento"]
OPENVIDU_CDR=false
OPENVIDU_CDR_PATH=/opt/openvidu/cdr
OPENVIDU_RECORDING=true
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_AUTOSTOP_TIMEOUT=120
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_COMPOSED_BASICAUTH=true
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_COMPOSED_URL=
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_CUSTOM_LAYOUT=/opt/openvidu/custom-layout
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_DEBUG=false
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_NOTIFICATION=publisher_moderator
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_PATH=/opt/openvidu/recordings
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_PUBLIC_ACCESS=true
OPENVIDU_RECORDING_VERSION=2.29.0
OPENVIDU_SECRET=*************************
OPENVIDU_SESSIONS_GARBAGE_INTERVAL=900
OPENVIDU_SESSIONS_GARBAGE_THRESHOLD=3600
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_ALLOW_TRANSCODING=false
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_FORCED_VIDEO_CODEC=MEDIA_SERVER_PREFERRED
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_VIDEO_MAX_RECV_BANDWIDTH=1000
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_VIDEO_MAX_SEND_BANDWIDTH=1000
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_VIDEO_MIN_RECV_BANDWIDTH=300
OPENVIDU_STREAMS_VIDEO_MIN_SEND_BANDWIDTH=300
OPENVIDU_WEBHOOK=true
OPENVIDU_WEBHOOK_ENDPOINT=https://backend.onrender.app/webhook
OPENVIDU_WEBHOOK_EVENTS=[sessionCreated,sessionDestroyed,participantJoined,participantLeft,webrtcConnectionCreated,webrtcConnectionDestroyed,recordingStatusChanged,filterEventDispatched,mediaNodeStatusChanged,nodeCrashed,nodeRecovered,broadcastStarted,broadcastStopped]
```

Mi frontend esta en angular y ahora mismo estoy usando momentáneamente el que me proporciona la documentación de **OpenVidu**, y en desarrollo cuando uso mi **localhost:4200**, se conecta perfectamente a mi servidor en Ubuntu, siempre y cuando mi archivo **proxy.conf.json** este de le siguiente manera:

```
{
"/": {
  "target": "https://servidorubuntu.com.co",
  "secure": false 
}
}
```

Pero cuando lo despliego en **Vercel** este **"secure"** en true o en false, no me conecta y sale este error:

```
error: null
headers: So {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://openvidufrontend.vercel.app/auth/login: 405 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 405
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://openvidufrontend.vercel.app/auth/login"
```

Que debería hacer en este caso para que el servidor en **Ubuntu** acepte las solicitudes, puedo de alguna forma especificar cual será la url del frontend?

Comment: Solo para aclarar, el error 405 es cuando el método no está permitido. Revisa que tipo solicitud te está dando el error (OPTIONS, GET, POST...) [Métodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). Y revisa si tu backend está bloqueando ese tipo de método

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte José, la cuestión es que mi backend el que uso como webhook no es el que me esta bloqueando las solicitudes, mas bien seria mi servidor donde tengo instalado OpenVidu

Comment: Mmm... Prueba a ver la configuración de Apache o Nginx que esté permitiendo los métodos. Por ejemplo en Apache es en Location y con AllowMethods POST.
Lo único que ya se me ocurre sería el Firewall que este bloqueando esas solicitudes, pero sería muy raro porque no daría un error 405, sino un 403 (Forbidden) y pasa lo mismo con permisos de carpetas.

Comment: También comentarte una cosa, los ficheros proxy.config.json no se suelen utilizar en entornos de producción. No sabría decirte ahora mismo si estás utilizando el proxy o no cuando lo buildeas. Entonces, es probable que tu servidor esté devolviendo un CORS. Puedes crear un .htaccess con las cabeceras para controlar el CORS en el backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el pasado, participé en un proyecto que empleaba OpenVidu. Sin embargo, observamos que el frontend proporcionado en la documentación no es adecuado para entornos de producción debido a fallos típicos de seguridad. Al acceder a las opciones de desarrollador y navegar a la sección de Red o Network, específicamente al archivo denominado "login" (generalmente resaltado en rojo debido a errores al intentar realizar solicitudes HTTP), se revelan las credenciales del formulario en la carga útil.

Es importante señalar que este tipo de vulnerabilidad puede resultar en la detección de fallos de seguridad por parte de los servidores, lo que puede llevar al bloqueo de la conexión.

Mi recomendación es crear un proyecto independiente y abordar estos problemas de seguridad. Al hacerlo, se puede asegurar un entorno más robusto y apto para su implementación en producción.